# static variable in php closure defined within a private class method

Tags: php, static, closures

So I re-wrote this to hopefully be clearer about what I'm attempting.  During some parsing of data someValue(s) associated with someCode(s) are received.  The intent is to capture a particularValue of a someCode having the lowest precedence, irrespective of the order the someCode/someValue (s) received.  The issue keeping this from working is that the closure is created every time the private function is called and the value of $precedenceOfCodeCaptured therefore is always reset to null.  If I could keep the closure around then things might work as intended.

```
private function Foo($particularValue, $someValue, $someCode) {

    switch ($someCode) {
        case:
            CODE1:
        case:
            CODE2:

            $c = function () use ($someCode, $someValue) {
                static $precedenceOfCodeCaptured = null;
                $precedenceArray = array(
                    CODE2 => 1,
                    CODE1 => 2
                );

                if ((is_null($someValue))) {//first time the case statement matched because $someValue==null
                    $precedenceOfCodeCaptured = $precedenceArray[$someCode];
                    $particularValue = someValue;
                } else if ($precedenceArray[$someCode] <= $precedenceOfCodeCaptured) {
                    $particularValue = someValue;
                }

            };

            $c();
            break;
            ...
    }

}//end of private method
```

Comment: Can you just declare the static outside of the closure and pass it in with the `use`?

Comment: No that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Every time Foo is called, you create a new function/closure, since you evaluate a function(), and that's what evaluating function() does!

If you'd like to have Foo() return the same function/closure each time, only evaluate it once.   Perhaps use a singleton pattern, where you'll check if some higher-scoped variable that holds the function has been initialized, and initialize it if not.

For example:

```
$c = null;

private function Foo(){

  if ($c == null) {
  $c = function() use ( $whatever){  
               static $x = 0;
               echo "x= $x";
               $x++; 
  ...
  };
}
```

$c();
}//end of private method

(but please don't use globals in your actual code!)

Comment: I revised my example to be clearer about my intention.  It seem like you are showing how to accomplish it with a global which isn't ideal, and likewise patarkk suggested a way that uses a class level static.  What would be best is if there were a way to have as you say "the same function/closure each time, that has its own static variable".  Having to define the static at class scope means that I'd have to have multiple (one for each case statement fall thru.

Comment: Look, the function() {} construct creates a new function/closure every time it's invoked, end of story.  If you want to reuse it to have access to the same function-scoped variables, you have to keep a reference to just one, not keep re-creating it.  Further, if you're not passing the closure out of your code, if you're just creating it and calling it, it is absolutely pointless.  Normal class methods will do exactly what you want.   Keep the "lowest precedence" value in a member field, update as needed.

Comment: Yes I understood the first time that the closure gets created every time it is evoked.  I understood also (before even trying the closure) that a class method would work.  However the point is to keep things very legible by having the function definition right where it is evoked as opposed to having a bunch of class methods that one has to search for.  I'll add that it seems limiting that the closure can't even (use) a function level static.

Comment: I see.   PHP supports nested functions for that - write the function() {} block with a name, as a statement instead of an expression, inside of the enclosing function.  The value you make a closure from the inner function still needs to be in an appropriate scope, however...

Comment: I don't understand "The value you make a closure from the inner".  Per my earlier comment, I thought one of the uses of closures was to have them inline to make things clearer.  That seems a good use as opposed to having class methods.  Do you disagree?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static $x = 0;
private function Foo() {
  $c = function() use ( $whatever){  
    echo "x= $x";
    self::$x++;
   ...
  };
  $c();
}
```

Comment: It works to have the class level static, but it isn't the cleanest per what I'm attempting.  I revised my example above to add details.

Comment: also see my other comment to BadZen because your suggestions seem to be almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class example{
    private function foo(){
        static $_closure;
        if( ! $_closure ){
            $_closure = function(){
                static $_state;
                /*  . . .  */
            };
        }
        $_closure();
    }
}
```

Note that the closure is static (it is created on first use, and not again), as is the variable that holds state inside the closure.

However, as stated in other answers, this is "pointless" at best.  `$_closure` *should* be another class method; `$_state` *should* be a class property (there is no need for static anything in the closure, in `foo()`, nor in the class).  It is not "cleaner" or more readable or performant (in fact, the opposite is likely true) to use a closure like this.

It might make sense if you were doing something like:

- returning the closure for use elsewhere
- dynamically creating the function at runtime (i.e., based on foo() args)
- something else dynamic and interesting

…but as it stands, this is simply the wrong approach.  The tools to do this already exist.